# Help in building nhibernate from source

Tags: nhibernate, msbuild, nant

I downloaded nant 0.86 beta which seems to be the latest release.

Now running:

nant default.build I get this error:

detected nant 0.86 beta 1, consider upgrading to a newer version when building for .net 3.5

default.build does not exist in this project

What am I doing wrong here?

**Update**
downloaded the nighly build, now running:

nant default.build

I get this error:

[script] scanning assembly "_bzhbyr9" for extensions

build failed

target 'default.build' does not exist in this project

Comment: You should ask in the NHibernate or NAnt mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

There are some sln files available in the trunk.  You can open these in Visual Studio and compile it that way.  Or you could even run MSBuild against them, if you need to use the command line.